# OpenVPN works with version 2.3.8 but not with openvpn 2.6.0

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have tried two different versions of OpenVPN

Version 2.3.8

```
OpenVPN 2.3.8 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [IPv6] built on Oct 30 2018
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO 2.09
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_http_proxy=yes enable_iproute2=no enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_lzo_stub=no enable_management=yes enable_multi=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_password_save=yes enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=no enable_plugin_auth_pam=no enable_plugin_down_root=no enable_plugins=no enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=no enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=yes enable_small=no enable_socks=yes enable_ssl=yes enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_plugindir='$(libdir)/openvpn/plugins' with_sysroot=no
```

and version 2.6.0

```
OpenVPN 2.6.0 [git:v2.6.0/b999466418dddb89] Windows-MSVC [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] [DCO] built on Feb  6 2023
library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022, LZO 2.10
Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater), amd64 executable
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2023 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: N/A
```

This is my config file:

```
client
remote servername.com 1194
proto tcp
remote servername.com 53
proto tcp
remote servername.com 80
proto tcp
remote servername.com 443
proto tcp
dev tun
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
verb 3
auth-user-pass
ca "cert_export_ca.crt"
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
route 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0
remote-cert-tls server
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDHDCCxxxx6sX2A=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

It works with 2.3.8 but with 2.6.0 I get this error:

```
2023-02-15 13:03:47 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=servername.com
2023-02-15 13:03:47 VERIFY KU OK
2023-02-15 13:03:47 Validating certificate extended key usage
2023-02-15 13:03:47 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2023-02-15 13:03:47 VERIFY EKU OK
2023-02-15 13:03:47 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=servername.com
2023-02-15 13:04:47 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2023-02-15 13:04:47 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2023-02-15 13:04:47 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
2023-02-15 13:04:47 Closing DCO interface
2023-02-15 13:04:47 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2023-02-15 13:04:47 Restart pause, 1 second(s)
```

I'm using windows 11 and running as administrator (simply to remove any problems permissions).

Anyone that knows what is going on and what I can do about it?

/peter

Comment: 3.0.7 might be to new (or the partner is too old). Check this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=280970